# pyspark recursive row chaining conversion to scala

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, recursive-query

I wrote a pyspark implementation of reading row over row to incrementally (and recursively) multiply a column value in sequence. Due to platform limitations on our side, I need to convert this to Scala now without UDAF. I looked [at this implementation](http://sqlandhadoop.com/how-to-implement-recursive-queries-in-spark/), but that one takes up long as the number of year_months grow as it needs # of temp tables as the # of year_months.

There are around 100 year_months and 70 departments giving total number of rows in this dataframe to be 7000. We need to take up the starting value (by first year month in the sequence) for each department and multiply it with next row value. The resulting multiplied factor needs to be multiplied over with next row and so on.

Example data:

```
department, productivity_ratio, year_month
101,1.00,2013-01-01
101,0.98,2013-02-01
101,1.01,2013-03-01
101,0.99,2013-04-01
...
102,1.00,2013-01-01
102,1.02,2013-02-01
102,0.96,2013-03-01
...
```

Expected result:

```
department,productivity_ratio,year_month,chained_productivity_ratio
101,1.00,2013-01-01,1.00
101,0.98,2013-02-01,0.98   (1.00*0.98)
101,1.01,2013-03-01,0.9898 (1.00*0.98*1.01)
101,0.99,2013-04-01,0.9799 (1.00*0.98*1.01*0.99)
...
102,1.00,2013-01-01,1.00   (reset to 1.00 as starting point as department name changed in sequence)
102,1.02,2013-02-01,1.02   (1.00*1.02)
102,0.96,2013-03-01,0.9792 (1.00*1.02*0.96)
...
```

Is there any way to implement this in faster way in scala either converting this into a loop over departments and looking at the productivity_ratio as a sequence to multiply with previous value or by changing the dataframe into a different data structure to avoid running into distributed sequencing problems.

Existing pyspark code:

```
%pyspark
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import StringIO

inputParquet = "s3://path/to/parquet/files/"
inputData = spark.read.parquet(inputParquet)
inputData.printSchema

root
|-- department: string
|-- productivity_ratio: double
|-- year_month: date

inputSorted=inputData.sort('department', 'year_month')
inputSortedNotnull=inputSorted.dropna()
finalInput=inputSortedNotnull.toPandas()

prev_dept = 999
prev_productivity_ratio = 1

new_productivity_chained = []

for t in finalInput.itertuples():
    if prev_dept == t[1]:
        new_productivity_chained.append(t[2] * prev_productivity_ratio)
        prev_productivity_ratio = t[2] * prev_productivity_ratio
    else:
        prev_productivity_ratio = 1
        new_productivity_chained.append(prev_productivity_ratio)
    prev_dept = t[1]

productivityChained = finalInput.assign(chained_productivity=new_productivity_chained)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`window lag`** function and do **`exp(sum(log(<column>)))`** to calculate the `chained_productivity_ratio` and all the functions we are using are **`spark inbuilt functions`** the performance will be great!

---

**`Example:`**

**`In Pyspark:`**

```
df.show()
#+----------+------------------+----------+
#|department|productivity_ratio|year_month|
#+----------+------------------+----------+
#|       101|              1.00|2013-01-01|
#|       101|              0.98|2013-02-01|
#|       101|              1.01|2013-03-01|
#|       101|              0.99|2013-04-01|
#|       102|              1.00|2013-01-01|
#|       102|              1.02|2013-02-01|
#|       102|              0.96|2013-03-01|
#+----------+------------------+----------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("department").orderBy("year_month")

df.withColumn("chained_productivity_ratio",exp(sum(log(col("productivity_ratio"))).over(w))).show()
#+----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+
#|department|productivity_ratio|year_month|chained_productivity_ratio|
#+----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+
#|       101|              1.00|2013-01-01|                       1.0|
#|       101|              0.98|2013-02-01|                      0.98|
#|       101|              1.01|2013-03-01|                    0.9898|
#|       101|              0.99|2013-04-01|        0.9799019999999999|
#|       102|              1.00|2013-01-01|                       1.0|
#|       102|              1.02|2013-02-01|                      1.02|
#|       102|              0.96|2013-03-01|                    0.9792|
#+----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+
```

---

**`In Scala:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val w = Window.partitionBy("department").orderBy("year_month")

df.withColumn("chained_productivity_ratio",exp(sum(log(col("productivity_ratio"))).over(w))).show()

//+----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+
//|department|productivity_ratio|year_month|chained_productivity_ratio|
//+----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+
//|       101|              1.00|2013-01-01|                       1.0|
//|       101|              0.98|2013-02-01|                      0.98|
//|       101|              1.01|2013-03-01|                    0.9898|
//|       101|              0.99|2013-04-01|        0.9799019999999999|
//|       102|              1.00|2013-01-01|                       1.0|
//|       102|              1.02|2013-02-01|                      1.02|
//|       102|              0.96|2013-03-01|                    0.9792|
//+----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+
```